# Leak in copyWithZone

Tags: iphone

The below code leaks.  Should I be autoreleasing newCopy before the return?

```
- (id) copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {

 Group *newCopy;
 newCopy = [[[self class] allocWithZone:zone] init];
 newCopy.groupName = [[[self groupName] copy] autorelease];

 for (int i=0; i < [[self linkArray] count]; i++) {
  [[newCopy linkArray] addObject:[[[[self linkArray] objectAtIndex:i] copy] autorelease]];
 }
 return newCopy; 
}
```

Comment: Leaks according to what?

Comment: According to the Leaks instrument

Answer (score 3):

This code isn't leaking. It's behaving as expected. The leaks instrument is pointing here because this is where the allocation was made. You should look at the caller, as that is likely where the leak is.